# Change length of GGPlot2 axes without changing axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced the following Box-Whisker Plot to display a dataset with GGPlot2 in R:

[image]

As you may notice however, the figure looks very "tall". Is there any way to further compress the length of the y-axis without changing the scale so none of my data gets cutoff?

My code is as follows:

```
healthy.control <- c(96.8,96.2,94.3,94.0,95.5,94.7)
healthy.exp <- c(median(79.64,79.13,79.04,79.49,79.51,79.90),
                 median(78.98,78.35,78.57,78.78,78.45,78.63),
                 median(77.12,77.90,77.43,77.07,77.85,77.81),
                 median(76.59,76.82,76.64,77.13,77.16,76.66),
                 median(78.00,78.26,78.08,77.79,78.35,78.34),
                 median(76.96,76.83,77.88,77.93,77.69,77.30))
  
adhd.control <- c(58.4,59.1,53.7,56.3,53.1,54.3)
adhd.exp <- c(median(49.12,48.39,48.68,48.50,48.00,48.32),
              median(48.96,48.94,49.24,49.30,48.78,49.15),
              median(44.97,45.24,45.26,45.00,44.87,45.02),
              median(46.95,47.05,47.04,46.80,47.70,46.97),
              median(44.28,44.20,44.42,44.37,44.43,44.67),
              median(45.04,45.56,44.76,45.56,45.50,45.02))

fig.data <- c(adhd.control,adhd.exp,healthy.control,healthy.exp)
group <- c(rep("Deficient WM",12),rep("Healthy WM",12))

Condition <- c(rep("Non-Impulsive",6),rep("Impulsive",6),rep("Non-Impulsive",6),rep("Impulsive",6))

data.summary <- data.frame(group,Condition,fig.data)

plot <- ggplot(data.summary, aes(x=group, y=fig.data,fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="red", outlier.shape=8,outlier.size=4) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40,100)) 

plot+labs(x="", y="MNIST TestSet Accuracy (%)\n")+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
```

Thank you kindly!

Comment: The shapes in ggplot preserve dimension appropriately when you rescale the plotting window. Simply reduce the height of your plotting window.

Answer (score 0):

Try log scale.  It will make it appear a bit closer as shown below.

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40,100), trans = "log10")
```

[image: output]